# User permissions on a costum content type

Tags: nodes, users

I've created a custom content type with fields (it's like a form), I've already added permission to logged users to use my form(content type) but I want to hide some checkboxes on this form only when user is not admin. so how to hide (remove) a part of fields of a content type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) for this

Features

- Enable field permissions on any entity, not just nodes.
- Role-based field permissions allowing different viewing patterned based on what access the user has.
- Author-level permissions allow viewing and editing of fields based on who the entity owner is.
- Permissions for each field are not enabled by default. Instead, administrators can enable these permissions explicitly for the fields where this feature is needed.
- Field permissions overview